# CardView doesn't display correctly in different screen densities?

Tags: java, android, xml, cardview

I have a ViewPager with Cardviews, cardviews are displays correctly on certaing devices but in most are displays slimly.
The ViewPager is in a Fragment.

I'm using LinearLayout to CardView definition, I tried Relative but I have same problem.

https://ibb.co/kyNF5Yz "Example from differents devices"

Item.xml
https://gist.github.com/Bryan9797/1eda5e7d02d1a12140115a539f164e3e

Fragment_bateria.xml
https://gist.github.com/Bryan9797/b5d7b16a6d0599b7fd7f593226a4523d

activity_main.xml
https://gist.github.com/Bryan9797/632461d73286afa5493167048b8e19c0

I expect display Cardview correctly on different devices.

Comment: Did you add layouts for the the different density screens?

Comment: Tell us what have you do so far: What have you analyzed, what were the result.s

Answer (score 0):

you can use sdp library for responsive XML for all devices.

https://github.com/intuit/sdp
you can install this dependency in gradle and us this sdp instead of dp.
you can set this sdp and set height to wrap_content in your xml layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_350sdp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/image"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Escritorio ejecutivo"
                android:textColor="#262626"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="Escritorio ejecutivo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```